# SSRS - using a where clause for a placeholder

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Using SSRS 2012 and I am trying to create a tablix.

I have a dataset which is querying a database for a set of results.  I want to use a where clause in my tablix to specify a client name.  This will be done on different columns.  So column A will have one client name and B another and so on.  My first column is the date and the tablix should group by the date as there are multiple entries for each day and I need to sum the results.

I have the following expression within my placeholder

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!clientname.Value = "Bob", Sum(Fields!s1_Weight.Value), 0))
```

So I need to sum all weights by date for the specified client name by date (one row for each date)

When I display the report I get 0's where there is no data, which is fine but where there should be data I get #error.  If I add a where clause to my dataset so for example

```
where clientname = 'Bob'
```

it works.

As I am adding multiple columns which need to look at different client names I can use this in my where clause.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try below expression

```
= IIF (Fields!clientname.Value = "Bob", Sum(Fields!s1_Weight.Value),0)
```